# Why RegSaveKey() fails with an error code 5 (access is denied) if the key to be saved is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

This question is independent of the programming language used.

Tested in Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 10 version 1803.

### Symptomps

**RegSaveKey()** fails with an error code 5 (*access is denied*) if the key to be saved is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

This error does not occur if a subkey is specified, e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM`.

This error also does not occur if the key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

### First Sample

Here, I use AutoIt to rapidly write [a sample code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gq2PACBoVaLKMXKakoVvBssj09Stx0GV/view?usp=sharing) that reproduce the error. I have also compiled the sample code to .EXE to make people easily look at the problem.

### Second sample

**REG.EXE**, which is a built-in Windows tool **written using Visual C++** (that's why the tags include C), have exactly the same problem as mentioned above. This is not surprising since according to my investigation, `REG.EXE SAVE` command actually use the undocumented **NtSaveKey()**. By the way, **RegSaveKey()** is internally make a call to **NtSaveKey()**.

```
REG.EXE SAVE "HKLM" "HKLM.hiv" /Y
```

The above command fails with an error "Access is denied". Note that I run the command as *Administrator*.

### Question

What is the cause of this error? Is there a way to make **RegSaveKey()** works for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (without specifying a subkey)?

### Update

My further test shows that **regedit.exe** have the same problem as mentioned above.

- Exporting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to a `.HIV` file fails; however, exporting it to a `.REG` file succeeds.
- Exporting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\<subkey>` to a `.HIV` file succeeds.
- Exporting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to a `.HIV` file succeeds.
- Exporting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\<subkey>` to a `.HIV` file succeeds.

Comment: I think the error hides the real issue: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is not a physically present key.

Comment: `NtSaveKey` internally call [`CmSaveKey`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/config/cmsavres.c#L1164). this api at very begin [*Disallow attempts to "save" the master hive*](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/config/cmsavres.c#L1198) - and return to you `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` at this [line](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/config/cmsavres.c#L1203)

Comment: What possible reason could you have for wanting to save the entire HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive?

Comment: @CareyGregory, the reason is because `regedit.exe` can do that without any problem if we export the entire HKLM key into a `.REG` file. My further test shows that `regedit.exe` also fails if we export the entire HKLM key into a `.HIV` file.

Comment: That's because regedit doesn't try to recreate the HKLM key itself from the .reg file. It simply enumerates through the .reg file and restores each key/value individually. I think @PaulStelian is correct that HKLM isn't a physical key you can directly manipulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All APIs that save a registry key internally call [`CmSaveKey`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/config/cmsavres.c#L1164). In the source code for this function, we see the following [*block of code*](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/config/cmsavres.c#L1198) at the beginning:

```
    //
    // Disallow attempts to "save" the master hive
    //
    Hive = KeyControlBlock->KeyHive;

    if (Hive == &CmpMasterHive->Hive) {
        return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
```

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (i.e. "\Registry\Machine") is in the master hive, so [`CmSaveKey`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/config/cmsavres.c#L1164) returns `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` (0xc0000022) to the caller. The Windows subsystem translates this status code to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5).

Comment: @eryksun i look i my own debugger - https://prnt.sc/jnse1a - i open `"\\registry\\machine"` key, look object pointer (`CM_KEY_BODY`) and get from it pointer to `KeyControlBlock->KeyHive` the value ( `0xFFFFB481BDE23000` in my concrete case) was exactly the same to `&CmpMasterHive->Hive`

Comment: @eryksun - ok, i really not very good in english, but i just check on different keys - for `\registry\machine` key i got `KeyBody->KeyControlBlock->KeyHive == &CmpMasterHive->Hive` exactly. while on another keys not. this is also i view even in user mode debugger )

Comment: @eryksun - look in debugger for several keys. https://i.imgur.com/enso9xd.png only what i try to say that for `HKLM` we got access denied exactly at this check `Hive == &CmpMasterHive->Hive`

Comment: yes, "\Registry" and "\Registry\User" also will be `Hive == &CmpMasterHive->Hive` but for `HKCU` which is `\Registry\User\<someuser>` - not. https://i.imgur.com/tzjLtrD.png

Comment: FYI, I upvoted your answer when I added the first comment. I just wanted to clarify the language about hives vs. keys within them, so as to not confuse the reader. One thing I'm not certain about is *why* it disallows saving the master hive.  It may be policy, or it may be nonsensical given allowing `CmRestoreKey` to restore the master hive at runtime is either impossible or just a really bad idea.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, now i understand english *is in the master hive* != *master hive*

Comment: @eryksun - think more exactly say that key is faster `CM_KEY_CONTROL_BLOCK` not a `HHIVE` but it located in the same `HHIVE`. `handle -> CM_KEY_BODY -> CM_KEY_CONTROL_BLOCK -> HHIVE`

Comment: FYI, for those unfamiliar with this pattern, the `KeyControlBlock` field of every Key object that references a particular key will reference the same key control block (i.e. a `CM_KEY_CONTROL_BLOCK` record). File systems are implemented similarly. A File object for a particular file/stream in a file system has an `FsContext` field that references a common file/stream control block (FCB or SCB).  Note also that a Key/File object may be referenced by multiple handles in multiple processes. So you can have multiple handles per object and multiple objects per control block.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, exactly. key handle point to the `CM_KEY_BODY` different(not duplicated) handles for the **same** key have different `CM_KEY_BODY` but inside `CM_KEY_BODY` exist pointer to the `CM_KEY_CONTROL_BLOCK` - and it already will be the same for the same key (even if `CM_KEY_BODY` different). like and `FILE_OBJECT` (in memory structure) can be different for the same file on disk, but `FCB` (`FsContext`) will be the same

Comment: @RbMm, OK, so saving either `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_USERS` will cause an access denied at `Hive == &CmpMasterHive->Hive`. I have confirmed this. I'm sure you are correct. Thank you very much.